# Convert columns to row in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab

My Table name is `osk,st,item`. osk fields are `stid,stock,free,npr,itemno`. st fields are `stid,name`. items fields are `id,name`. And i have multiple schema. Every schemas have this table

```
select i.name,st.name,stock,freestock from osk,st,items i where i.id=osk.itemno 
and st.stid=osk.stid
```

this query return result like this

```
  Name   St.Name    Stock   FreeStock
   A        B         10        20
   D        B         10        10
   C        E         12        10
```

But I want

```
 Name    B (stock)     B(Free)   E(Stock)  E (Free Stock)
  A        10           20         -           -
  D        10           10         -           -
  C        -            -          12          10
```

How to acheive this. (i have multiple schema. all schemas have this table i want retrive from all schema)

am using **postgresql 9.3**. IF possible to use CrossTab? How to use it?

Comment: @Wolph Sir I think this is something different in that example?.

Comment: @Wolph Please do not link to the old versions of Postgres. Use `docs/current/static` instead of `docs/8.3/static`.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: Oops, seems I miss read, I thought we were talking about Postgres 8.3 here, seems it's 9.3 :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table like this (had to guess since you didn't provide the exact table definitions):

```
create table some_table (
  name text,
  stname text,
  stock int,
  freestock int
 );

insert into some_table values
('A', 'B', 10, 20),
('D', 'B', 10, 10),
('C', 'E', 12, 10);
```

Now you can use the `crosstab` function like this as documented here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html

```
create extension if not exists tablefunc;

select coalesce(stock.name, freestock.name) as name,
       stock.b as "B (stock)",
       freestock.b as "B (free)",
       stock.e as "E (stock)",
       freestock.e as "E (free)"
from 
    crosstab('
        select name,
            stname,
            stock
        from some_table
    ', '
        select distinct stname
        from some_table
        order by stname
    ') as stock(name text, b int, e int)
full outer join 
    crosstab('
        select name,
            stname,
            freestock
        from some_table
    ', '
        select distinct stname
        from some_table
        order by stname
    ') as freestock(name text, b int, e int)
on stock.name = freestock.name;
```

Which results in:

```
 name | B (stock) | B (free) | E (stock) | E (free)
------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------
 A    |        10 |       20 |           |
 C    |           |          |        12 |       10
 D    |        10 |       10 |           |
(3 rows)
```

Comment: i have one doubt `select name,
            stname,
            stock
        from some_table`  `stock(name text, b int, e int)` b int how is possible sir. Because in table stname is text.

Comment: how to worte the the same query for multiple schemas

Comment: @SATSON: the `b int` is possible because `crosstab` will split your results to columns.

Can you clarify what you mean with multiple schemas here? If you're talking about multiple postgres schema's than it's simply adding them to the `search_path` or prefixing the tablenames.

Comment: how to get all data's in multiple schema. every schema have same table but different values. So how to get the all schema values

Comment: There is no generic way since your results would have a variable amount of columns, you need to define how much columns/categories to expect here. If you need it flexible than you might want to consider returning these per row instead of per column.